# Using SQLite in Android to get RowID

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I am creating an app to record assignments for different classes. Each class has it's own unique ID so the assignments listed for each class don't overlap into other classes. Here is a method I made to find the rowid for a certain class.

```
public int getIdFromClassName(String className){
    String query = "SELECT rowid FROM " + CLASSES_TABLE_NAME + " WHERE " + CLASSES_COLUMN_NAME + " = '" + className + "'";
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor res = db.rawQuery(query, null);
    return res.getColumnIndex("id");
}
```

However, this always returns a value of -1.

Any thoughts on what to change to return the proper rowid value?

EDIT:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    db.execSQL(
            "create table " + CLASSES_TABLE_NAME + " " +
                    "(id integer primary key, " + CLASSES_COLUMN_NAME + " text)"
    );
    db.execSQL(
            "create table " + ASSIGNMENTS_TABLE_NAME + " " +
                    "(id integer primary key, " + ASSIGNMENTS_COLUMN_NAME + " text, " + ASSIGNMENTS_COLUMN_TOTAL_POINTS
                    + " INTEGER, " + ASSIGNMENTS_COLUMN_CLASS_ID + " INTEGER)");

}
```

Comment: have you tried this? return res.getString( res.getColumnIndex("id") );

Comment: That would return a String, but I am looking for the id in the form of an int

Comment: it depends...data type you are using for id...i think you can also use getInt ..if its data type is integer

Comment: if still not resolved..you can check res.moveToFirst() method

Comment: if you dont know what columns your `Cursor` holds call `DatabaseUtils.dumpCursor`

Answer (score 2):

Try this query below to create a new column name `rowID`:

```
Cursor cursor= db.rawQuery("SELECT *,"+CLASSES_TABLE_NAME +".rowid AS rowID"+" FROM "+CLASSES_TABLE_NAME , null);
```

And after this query you can fetch the real `rowid` from the `rowID` column :

```
while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
        long chatRow=cursor.getLong(
                cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("rowID"));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The column returned by your query is called `rowid`, so you will not find a column called `id`.

Ensure that you use the same column name in the query and in the call to `getColumnIndex`.

And the index of this column is always zero; you also need to read the actual value from the column:

```java
int colIndex = res.getColumnIndexOrThrow("rowid"); // = 0
if (res.moveToFirst()) {
    return res.getInt(colIndex);
} else {
    // not found
}
```

However, Android has an [helper function](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/DatabaseUtils.html#longForQuery%28android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[]%29) that makes it much easier to read a single value:

```java
public int getIdFromClassName(String className){
    String query = "SELECT rowid" +
                   " FROM " + CLASSES_TABLE_NAME +
                   " WHERE " + CLASSES_COLUMN_NAME + " = ?;";
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    return DatabaseUtils.longForQuery(db, query, new String[]{ className });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

res.getColumnIndex("id") is going to get you the column index of the column with the name "id". and since you are getting -1, it cant find it.. are you sure your id column is not "_id"?

To get this to work you should do something like this..

```
res.getLong(res.getColumnIndex("_id"));
```

[Cursor.getColumnIndex()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html#getColumnIndex(java.lang.String))

[Cursor.getLong()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html#getLong(int))

(I would recommend you use getLong() rather than getInt() because SQLite database ID's can get larger than int's).

Comment: That returns the exeption: android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index -1 requested, with a size of 1

Comment: @Kinoscorpia What is the name of your ID column? It will return -1 if it cant find "id" or "_id".

EDIT: Judging by the SQL, the name of your column is "rowid" correct? so  try 

res.getLong(res.getColumnIndex("rowid"));

Comment: Added the onCreate method

Comment: You need to check your SQL statement.. it should be "SELECT id FROM " + CLASSES_TABLE_NAME + " WHERE " + CLASSES_COLUMN_NAME + " = '" + className + "'";

Answer (score 0):

```
public int getIdFromClassName(String className) {
        String query = "SELECT rowid FROM " + CLASSES_TABLE_NAME + " WHERE "
                + CLASSES_COLUMN_NAME + " = '" + className + "'";
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor res = db.rawQuery(query, null);
        if (res != null) {
            if (res.moveToFirst()) {
                do {
                    return Integer.parseInt(res.getString(res.getColumnIndex("id"))); // if your column name is rowid then replace id with rowid
                } while (res.moveToNext());
            }
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(context, "cursor is null", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
```

Check your Cursor if its null check your Log that your table is created successfully and if its not null make sure your table has column `id` in it.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
public int getIdFromClassName(String className){
String query = "SELECT id FROM " + CLASSES_TABLE_NAME + " WHERE " + CLASSES_COLUMN_NAME + " = '" + className + "'";
SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
Cursor res = db.rawQuery(query, null);
int id=-1;
If(res!=null&&res.moveToFirst())
id=res.getInt(res.getColumnIndex("id"));
return id;
}
```